# Adding an index to a row based on a condition of another column - R

Tags: r, indexing, time

I have data from an automated telephone survey.  This survey includes 2 call-backs when a caller gets disconnected.

Here is data from one respondent.  I have thousands, though, with similar data that I need to process.

The column is the respondent's ID, the second is an ordering ID (because the timestamp isn't out to milliseconds), the third is the interaction between the survey tool and the respondent's phone (essentially the respondent), the fourth is the datetime stamp, and the final is the difference in time between rows that I calculated at an earlier point.

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(c(
111,    2340,   'Enqueueing call',  '12/2/19 14:53:57', NA,
111,    6174,   'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/2/19 20:14:22', 19225,
111,    10386,  'Answer',   '12/3/19 15:48:56', 70474,
111,    10387,  'Contacted',    '12/3/19 15:48:56', 0,
111,    10388,  'Intro',    '12/3/19 15:48:56', 0,
111,    10389,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:49:16', 20,
111,    10390,  'Intro',    '12/3/19 15:49:16', 0,
111,    10391,  '1',    '12/3/19 15:49:30', 14,
111,    10392,  'Started',  '12/3/19 15:49:30', 0,
111,    10393,  'Q1',   '12/3/19 15:49:30', 0,
111,    10394,  '1',    '12/3/19 15:49:45', 15,
111,    10395,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:49:45', 0,
111,    10396,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:49:54', 9,
111,    10397,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:49:54', 0,
111,    10398,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:50:03', 9,
111,    10399,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:50:03', 0,
111,    10400,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:50:11', 8,
111,    17658,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '12/4/19 17:50:27', 93616,
111,    19932,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/4/19 20:45:17', 10490,
111,    25647,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/5/19 20:33:27', 85690,
111,    31516,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/6/19 20:17:18', 85431,
111,    36781,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/7/19 20:02:16', 85498,
111,    38718,  'Answer',   '12/8/19 10:24:07', 51711,
111,    38719,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:07', 0,
111,    38720,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:16', 9,
111,    38721,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:16', 0,
111,    38722,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:24', 8,
111,    38723,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:24', 0,
111,    38724,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:33', 9,
111,    45339,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '12/9/19 12:25:08', 93635,
111,    49026,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/9/19 20:31:26', 29178,
111,    53972,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/10/19 20:14:38',    85392,
111,    58277,  'Answer',   '12/11/19 17:55:29',    78051,
111,    58278,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:29',    0,
111,    58279,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:55:38',    9,
111,    58280,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:38',    0,
111,    58281,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:55:46',    8,
111,    58282,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:46',    0,
111,    58283,  '61',   '12/11/19 17:55:57',    11,
111,    58284,  'Q3',   '12/11/19 17:55:57',    0,
111,    58285,  '4',    '12/11/19 17:56:13',    16,
111,    58286,  'Q4',   '12/11/19 17:56:13',    0,
111,    58288,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:56:42',    29,
111,    58289,  'Interim partial',  '12/11/19 17:56:42',    0,
111,    58290,  'Q5',   '12/11/19 17:56:42',    0,
111,    58291,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:56:59',    17,
111,    58292,  'Q6',   '12/11/19 17:56:59',    0,
111,    58293,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:25',    26,
111,    58294,  'Q7',   '12/11/19 17:57:25',    0,
111,    58295,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:38',    13,
111,    58296,  'Q8',   '12/11/19 17:57:38',    0,
111,    58297,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:50',    12,
111,    58298,  'Q9',   '12/11/19 17:57:50',    0,
111,    58299,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:58:09',    19,
111,    58300,  'Q9',   '12/11/19 17:58:09',    0,
111,    58301,  '10',   '12/11/19 17:58:32',    23,
111,    58302,  'Q10',  '12/11/19 17:58:32',    0,
111,    58303,  '1',    '12/11/19 17:58:49',    17,
111,    58304,  'Q11',  '12/11/19 17:58:49',    0,
111,    58307,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:59:02',    13,
111,    58308,  'Q12',  '12/11/19 17:59:02',    0,
111,    58309,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:59:23',    21,
111,    58310,  'Q13',  '12/11/19 17:59:23',    0,
111,    58311,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:59:44',    21,
111,    58312,  'Q13',  '12/11/19 17:59:44',    0,
111,    58313,  '4',    '12/11/19 17:59:51',    7,
111,    58314,  'Q14',  '12/11/19 17:59:51',    0,
111,    58318,  '2',    '12/11/19 18:00:19',    28,
111,    58319,  'Q15',  '12/11/19 18:00:19',    0,
111,    58320,  '3',    '12/11/19 18:00:36',    17,
111,    58321,  'Q16',  '12/11/19 18:00:36',    0,
111,    58322,  '4',    '12/11/19 18:01:04',    28,
111,    58323,  'Q17',  '12/11/19 18:01:04',    0,
111,    58324,  '1',    '12/11/19 18:01:18',    14,
111,    58325,  'Q18',  '12/11/19 18:01:18',    0,
111,    58327,  '4',    '12/11/19 18:01:42',    24,
111,    58328,  'Q19',  '12/11/19 18:01:42',    0,
111,    58329,  '1',    '12/11/19 18:01:56',    14,
111,    58330,  'Q20',  '12/11/19 18:01:56',    0,
111,    58331,  '1',    '12/11/19 18:02:19',    23,
111,    58332,  'Q21',  '12/11/19 18:02:19',    0,
111,    58333,  '1',    '12/11/19 18:02:28',    9,
111,    58334,  'Q22',  '12/11/19 18:02:28',    0,
111,    58335,  '2',    '12/11/19 18:02:52',    24,
111,    58336,  'Completed',    '12/11/19 18:02:52',    0,
111,    58337,  'Complete Message', '12/11/19 18:02:52',    0,
111,    58338,  'Thank you',    '12/11/19 18:02:52',    0),
nrow=87, ncol=5, byrow=T,
dimnames=list(c(NULL), c("Respondent.ID", "order.ID", "Interaction", "Datetime", "difftime"))))
```

I need to sum up the time for difftime but only based on certain conditions.  Essentially, I want the data to look like the below, so I can sum the time where Include = 1.

Condition 1:  All the rows between the row after Interaction = "Answer" and the row before Interaction = "Timeout. Call failed." should be Include = 1.
Condition 2:  All the rows between the row after Interaction = "Answer" and the row before Interaction = "Completed" should be Include = 1.

```
new <- data.frame(matrix(c(
111,    2340,   'Enqueueing call',  '   12/2/19 14:53:57    ',  NA, 0,
111,    6174,   'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/2/19 20:14:22    ',  19225,  0,
111,    10386,  'Answer',   '   12/3/19 15:48:56    ',  70474,  0,
111,    10387,  'Contacted',    '   12/3/19 15:48:56    ',  0,  1,
111,    10388,  'Intro',    '   12/3/19 15:48:56    ',  0,  1,
111,    10389,  'Timeout',  '   12/3/19 15:49:16    ',  20, 1,
111,    10390,  'Intro',    '   12/3/19 15:49:16    ',  0,  1,
111,    10391,  '1',    '   12/3/19 15:49:30    ',  14, 1,
111,    10392,  'Started',  '   12/3/19 15:49:30    ',  0,  1,
111,    10393,  'Q1',   '   12/3/19 15:49:30    ',  0,  1,
111,    10394,  '1',    '   12/3/19 15:49:45    ',  15, 1,
111,    10395,  'Q2',   '   12/3/19 15:49:45    ',  0,  1,
111,    10396,  'Timeout',  '   12/3/19 15:49:54    ',  9,  1,
111,    10397,  'Q2',   '   12/3/19 15:49:54    ',  0,  1,
111,    10398,  'Timeout',  '   12/3/19 15:50:03    ',  9,  1,
111,    10399,  'Q2',   '   12/3/19 15:50:03    ',  0,  1,
111,    10400,  'Timeout',  '   12/3/19 15:50:11    ',  8,  1,
111,    17658,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '   12/4/19 17:50:27    ',  93616,  0,
111,    19932,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/4/19 20:45:17    ',  10490,  0,
111,    25647,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/5/19 20:33:27    ',  85690,  0,
111,    31516,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/6/19 20:17:18    ',  85431,  0,
111,    36781,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/7/19 20:02:16    ',  85498,  0,
111,    38718,  'Answer',   '   12/8/19 10:24:07    ',  51711,  0,
111,    38719,  'Q2',   '   12/8/19 10:24:07    ',  0,  1,
111,    38720,  'Timeout',  '   12/8/19 10:24:16    ',  9,  1,
111,    38721,  'Q2',   '   12/8/19 10:24:16    ',  0,  1,
111,    38722,  'Timeout',  '   12/8/19 10:24:24    ',  8,  1,
111,    38723,  'Q2',   '   12/8/19 10:24:24    ',  0,  1,
111,    38724,  'Timeout',  '   12/8/19 10:24:33    ',  9,  1,
111,    45339,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '   12/9/19 12:25:08    ',  93635,  0,
111,    49026,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/9/19 20:31:26    ',  29178,  0,
111,    53972,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '   12/10/19 20:14:38   ',  85392,  0,
111,    58277,  'Answer',   '   12/11/19 17:55:29   ',  78051,  0,
111,    58278,  'Q2',   '   12/11/19 17:55:29   ',  0,  1,
111,    58279,  'Timeout',  '   12/11/19 17:55:38   ',  9,  1,
111,    58280,  'Q2',   '   12/11/19 17:55:38   ',  0,  1,
111,    58281,  'Timeout',  '   12/11/19 17:55:46   ',  8,  1,
111,    58282,  'Q2',   '   12/11/19 17:55:46   ',  0,  1,
111,    58283,  '61',   '   12/11/19 17:55:57   ',  11, 1,
111,    58284,  'Q3',   '   12/11/19 17:55:57   ',  0,  1,
111,    58285,  '4',    '   12/11/19 17:56:13   ',  16, 1,
111,    58286,  'Q4',   '   12/11/19 17:56:13   ',  0,  1,
111,    58288,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:56:42   ',  29, 1,
111,    58289,  'Interim partial',  '   12/11/19 17:56:42   ',  0,  1,
111,    58290,  'Q5',   '   12/11/19 17:56:42   ',  0,  1,
111,    58291,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:56:59   ',  17, 1,
111,    58292,  'Q6',   '   12/11/19 17:56:59   ',  0,  1,
111,    58293,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:57:25   ',  26, 1,
111,    58294,  'Q7',   '   12/11/19 17:57:25   ',  0,  1,
111,    58295,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:57:38   ',  13, 1,
111,    58296,  'Q8',   '   12/11/19 17:57:38   ',  0,  1,
111,    58297,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:57:50   ',  12, 1,
111,    58298,  'Q9',   '   12/11/19 17:57:50   ',  0,  1,
111,    58299,  'Timeout',  '   12/11/19 17:58:09   ',  19, 1,
111,    58300,  'Q9',   '   12/11/19 17:58:09   ',  0,  1,
111,    58301,  '10',   '   12/11/19 17:58:32   ',  23, 1,
111,    58302,  'Q10',  '   12/11/19 17:58:32   ',  0,  1,
111,    58303,  '1',    '   12/11/19 17:58:49   ',  17, 1,
111,    58304,  'Q11',  '   12/11/19 17:58:49   ',  0,  1,
111,    58307,  '3',    '   12/11/19 17:59:02   ',  13, 1,
111,    58308,  'Q12',  '   12/11/19 17:59:02   ',  0,  1,
111,    58309,  'Timeout',  '   12/11/19 17:59:23   ',  21, 1,
111,    58310,  'Q13',  '   12/11/19 17:59:23   ',  0,  1,
111,    58311,  'Timeout',  '   12/11/19 17:59:44   ',  21, 1,
111,    58312,  'Q13',  '   12/11/19 17:59:44   ',  0,  1,
111,    58313,  '4',    '   12/11/19 17:59:51   ',  7,  1,
111,    58314,  'Q14',  '   12/11/19 17:59:51   ',  0,  1,
111,    58318,  '2',    '   12/11/19 18:00:19   ',  28, 1,
111,    58319,  'Q15',  '   12/11/19 18:00:19   ',  0,  1,
111,    58320,  '3',    '   12/11/19 18:00:36   ',  17, 1,
111,    58321,  'Q16',  '   12/11/19 18:00:36   ',  0,  1,
111,    58322,  '4',    '   12/11/19 18:01:04   ',  28, 1,
111,    58323,  'Q17',  '   12/11/19 18:01:04   ',  0,  1,
111,    58324,  '1',    '   12/11/19 18:01:18   ',  14, 1,
111,    58325,  'Q18',  '   12/11/19 18:01:18   ',  0,  1,
111,    58327,  '4',    '   12/11/19 18:01:42   ',  24, 1,
111,    58328,  'Q19',  '   12/11/19 18:01:42   ',  0,  1,
111,    58329,  '1',    '   12/11/19 18:01:56   ',  14, 1,
111,    58330,  'Q20',  '   12/11/19 18:01:56   ',  0,  1,
111,    58331,  '1',    '   12/11/19 18:02:19   ',  23, 1,
111,    58332,  'Q21',  '   12/11/19 18:02:19   ',  0,  1,
111,    58333,  '1',    '   12/11/19 18:02:28   ',  9,  1,
111,    58334,  'Q22',  '   12/11/19 18:02:28   ',  0,  1,
111,    58335,  '2',    '   12/11/19 18:02:52   ',  24, 1,
111,    58336,  'Completed',    '   12/11/19 18:02:52   ',  0,  0,
111,    58337,  'Complete Message', '   12/11/19 18:02:52   ',  0,  0,
111,    58338,  'Thank you',    '   12/11/19 18:02:52   ',  0,  0),
nrow=87, ncol=6, byrow=T,
dimnames=list(c(NULL), c("Respondent.ID", "order.ID", "Response", "Datetime", "difftime", "Include"))))
```

I tried adding columns indicating where the start and stop positions where but couldn't figure out how to index the rows between start and stop.

**UPDATE**

I found a case where we cut off the survey and end up cutting off some respondents.  When that happens they don't get a Stop code in their Interaction data.  As a result, the rle isn't picking up the final run length we want to capture.  I've fiddled around with it but this is a new thing for me so I thought I'd post a version of the test dataset  above that mimics the situation.

```
test2 <- data.frame(matrix(c(
111,    2340,   'Enqueueing call',  '12/2/19 14:53:57', NA,
111,    6174,   'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/2/19 20:14:22', 19225,
111,    10386,  'Answer',   '12/3/19 15:48:56', 70474,
111,    10387,  'Contacted',    '12/3/19 15:48:56', 0,
111,    10388,  'Intro',    '12/3/19 15:48:56', 0,
111,    10389,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:49:16', 20,
111,    10390,  'Intro',    '12/3/19 15:49:16', 0,
111,    10391,  '1',    '12/3/19 15:49:30', 14,
111,    10392,  'Started',  '12/3/19 15:49:30', 0,
111,    10393,  'Q1',   '12/3/19 15:49:30', 0,
111,    10394,  '1',    '12/3/19 15:49:45', 15,
111,    10395,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:49:45', 0,
111,    10396,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:49:54', 9,
111,    10397,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:49:54', 0,
111,    10398,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:50:03', 9,
111,    10399,  'Q2',   '12/3/19 15:50:03', 0,
111,    10400,  'Timeout',  '12/3/19 15:50:11', 8,
111,    17658,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '12/4/19 17:50:27', 93616,
111,    19932,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/4/19 20:45:17', 10490,
111,    25647,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/5/19 20:33:27', 85690,
111,    31516,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/6/19 20:17:18', 85431,
111,    36781,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/7/19 20:02:16', 85498,
111,    38718,  'Answer',   '12/8/19 10:24:07', 51711,
111,    38719,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:07', 0,
111,    38720,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:16', 9,
111,    38721,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:16', 0,
111,    38722,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:24', 8,
111,    38723,  'Q2',   '12/8/19 10:24:24', 0,
111,    38724,  'Timeout',  '12/8/19 10:24:33', 9,
111,    45339,  'Timeout. Call failed.',    '12/9/19 12:25:08', 93635,
111,    49026,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/9/19 20:31:26', 29178,
111,    53972,  'Call expired, will be retried in next schedule window',    '12/10/19 20:14:38',    85392,
111,    58277,  'Answer',   '12/11/19 17:55:29',    78051,
111,    58278,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:29',    0,
111,    58279,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:55:38',    9,
111,    58280,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:38',    0,
111,    58281,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:55:46',    8,
111,    58282,  'Q2',   '12/11/19 17:55:46',    0,
111,    58283,  '61',   '12/11/19 17:55:57',    11,
111,    58284,  'Q3',   '12/11/19 17:55:57',    0,
111,    58285,  '4',    '12/11/19 17:56:13',    16,
111,    58286,  'Q4',   '12/11/19 17:56:13',    0,
111,    58288,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:56:42',    29,
111,    58289,  'Interim partial',  '12/11/19 17:56:42',    0,
111,    58290,  'Q5',   '12/11/19 17:56:42',    0,
111,    58291,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:56:59',    17,
111,    58292,  'Q6',   '12/11/19 17:56:59',    0,
111,    58293,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:25',    26,
111,    58294,  'Q7',   '12/11/19 17:57:25',    0,
111,    58295,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:38',    13,
111,    58296,  'Q8',   '12/11/19 17:57:38',    0,
111,    58297,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:57:50',    12,
111,    58298,  'Q9',   '12/11/19 17:57:50',    0,
111,    58299,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:58:09',    19,
111,    58300,  'Q9',   '12/11/19 17:58:09',    0,
111,    58301,  '10',   '12/11/19 17:58:32',    23,
111,    58302,  'Q10',  '12/11/19 17:58:32',    0,
111,    58303,  '1',    '12/11/19 17:58:49',    17,
111,    58304,  'Q11',  '12/11/19 17:58:49',    0,
111,    58307,  '3',    '12/11/19 17:59:02',    13,
111,    58308,  'Q12',  '12/11/19 17:59:02',    0,
111,    58309,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:59:23',    21,
111,    58310,  'Q13',  '12/11/19 17:59:23',    0,
111,    58311,  'Timeout',  '12/11/19 17:59:44',    21,
111,    58312,  'Q13',  '12/11/19 17:59:44',    0,
111,    58313,  '4',    '12/11/19 17:59:51',    7,
111,    58314,  'Q14',  '12/11/19 17:59:51',    0,
111,    58318,  '2',    '12/11/19 18:00:19',    28
),
nrow=68, ncol=5, byrow=T,
dimnames=list(c(NULL), c("Respondent.ID", "order.ID", "Interaction", "Datetime", "difftime"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of problems can usually be solved with run length encoding.
Suppose in the code below that 'test' is the first dataset you posted and 'new' is the second dataset.

We would first need to figure out what entries in your data are start and stop positions or 'categories'.

```
start <- "Answer"
stop <- c("Timeout. Call failed.", "Completed")

cat <- ifelse(test$Interaction %in% start, "start",
              ifelse(test$Interaction %in% stop, "stop", "other"))
```

Subsequently, we can run length encode `cat`, and get the start and stop positions, and based on these figure out what rows should be different.

```
rle <- rle(cat)
start_positions <- which(rle$values == "start")
stop_positions  <- which(rle$values == "stop")

# Points that need to be changed are after starts and before stops
# The intersect ensures that we don't flag a 'start', 'other', 'start' sequence to be changed
change <- intersect(start_positions + 1, stop_positions - 1)
```

Finally, we need to encode the `change` as 1 and the rest as 0 and put it back into the data:

```
rle$values <- rep.int(0, length(rle$values))
rle$values[change] <- 1

test$Include <- inverse.rle(rle)
```

And we can check wether the result would be correct by making a confusion matrix:

```
> table(test = test$Include, new = new$Include)
    new
test  0  1
   0 16  0
   1  0 71
```

EDIT: The following should work if there is no proper stop position. I've assumed that the data is ordered on `Respondent.ID`, so if that assumption is not true maybe this might not be the best way. It was not clear to me whether undocumented stops should be included or excluded. In the code below, they are included.

```
start <- "Answer"
stop <- c("Timeout. Call failed.", "Completed")

cat <- ifelse(test2$Interaction %in% start, "start",
              ifelse(test2$Interaction %in% stop, "stop", "other"))

responder_rle <- rle(as.character(test2$Respondent.ID))
cat[cumsum(responder_rle$lengths)] <- "unplannedstop"

rle <- rle(cat)
start_positions <- which(rle$values == "start")
stop_positions  <- which(rle$values == "stop")
unplanned_stop  <- which(rle$values == "unplannedstop")

change <- c(intersect(start_positions + 1, 
                      c(stop_positions, unplanned_stop) - 1), 
            unplanned_stop)

rle$values <- rep.int(0, length(rle$values))
rle$values[change] <- 1

test2$Include <- inverse.rle(rle)
```

If the unplanned stop should not be included, you could use the following for the `change` variable:

```
change <- intersect(start_positions + 1, c(stop_positions, unplanned_stop) - 1)
```

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, this solutions largely works but I ran into one special circumstance where it doesn't.  When we turned the survey off ourselves, some respondents were cut off and they don't have a Stop code in their Response data. In these cases their Start position for that run length isn't marked. I'll set up an example dataset and post it.

Comment: I've posted the code to adress this circumstance in an edit. I didn't have any test data for multiple responders, so be sure to check the output is as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Just tested it and it works great, so thanks, again!